# Hide the particular option after the selected option in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some option value like below now what im trying to do is ?

I need to hide the option value after the selected option. How can i do that by using Jquery ?

**HTML**

```
<select name="month" id="month">
    <option val="January">January</option>
    <option val="February">February</option>
    <option val="March">March</option>
    <option val="April">April</option>
    <option val="May">May</option>
    <option val="June" selected="selected">June</option>
    <option val="July">July</option>
    <option val="August">August</option>
    <option val="September">September</option>
    <option val="October">October</option>
    <option val="November">November</option>
    <option val="December">December</option>
</select>
```

**Expected Result**

```
 <select name="month" id="month">
        <option val="January">January</option>
        <option val="February">February</option>
        <option val="March">March</option>
        <option val="April">April</option>
        <option val="May">May</option>
        <option val="June" selected="selected">June</option>
        <option val="July" style="display:none;">July</option>
        <option val="August" style="display:none;">August</option>
        <option val="September" style="display:none;">September</option>
        <option val="October" style="display:none;">October</option>
        <option val="November" style="display:none;">November</option>
        <option val="December" style="display:none;">December</option>
    </select>
```

How can i achieve this in jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#month option:selected').nextAll().hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="month" id="month">
    <option val="January">January</option>
    <option val="February">February</option>
    <option val="March">March</option>
    <option val="April">April</option>
    <option val="May">May</option>
    <option val="June" selected="selected">June</option>
    <option val="July">July</option>
    <option val="August">August</option>
    <option val="September">September</option>
    <option val="October">October</option>
    <option val="November">November</option>
    <option val="December">December</option>
</select>
```

Use [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

> Description: Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Answer (score 2):

Select all the options after the checked one and hide them: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq537tas/1/

`$('option:checked ~ option').hide()`

Or use plain CSS without jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq537tas/

```
#month option + option:checked ~ option {
  display:none;
}
```

I have added additional first option that doesn't hide the rest when checked. Otherwise there would be no way to change the month if January was selected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('option').filter(':gt('+jQuery('option:selected').index()+')').hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="month" id="month">
    <option val="January">January</option>
    <option val="February">February</option>
    <option val="March">March</option>
    <option val="April">April</option>
    <option val="May">May</option>
    <option val="June" selected="selected">June</option>
    <option val="July">July</option>
    <option val="August">August</option>
    <option val="September">September</option>
    <option val="October">October</option>
    <option val="November">November</option>
    <option val="December">December</option>
</select>
```